# Download streaming RTSP protocol

Tags: c#, php, streaming, rtsp

Are there any class or snippet in PHP or C# (better in php if could be), to download video from an streaming source that uses RTSP protocol?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best Regards.

Jose.

Comment: How do you want to download it as? RTSP carries video/audio fragments, and to hold it (and play it) you need to have some container format like MP4, QTFF, AVI, MKV... Or you just want to dump RTP stream to HDD?

Comment: Hi Cipi, the original file is a .3gp and i just want to save it. Do you know how could save it?

Regards.
Jose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to call out to an external program to do this. Check out `mplayer -dumpstream` and, if that fails, `rtmpdump`. Keep in mind that saving the stream will take a long time, so it's almost certainly better done in an external process that spawns a number of worker. Your web application can then communicate with the process to pass jobs and results back and forth.